# Blender crashes when I try to render with HDRI lighting

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, hdri

I'm a long time 3D artist but a brand new Blender user (mfs converted me xD)

I recently purchased a beefed up Rog Strix 15 with AMD radeon 6800M GPU. I have installed all the needed drivers for AMD support and what not and Blender seem to work fine now. My GPU shows in the system, works fine with Evee and Cycles (or so I thought).

Normally the scenes are rendering fine, no issue, if I have physical lights in the scene. However, as soon as I try to add HDRI to the scene and try to render with Cycles, it crashes. Evee is working fine, the issue is specific to Cycles on GPU compute setting. Cycles on CPU seems fine too.

Is this a known issue and is there a fix? Help a brother out.